# Use SQL Server check constraints or Application logic to keep Referential Integrity on User Id?

Tags: sql-server, referential-integrity

For Audit purpose each of my Sql Server tables in a database has a 'LastUpdatedUserId' and 'CreateduserId' column

These columns are foreign keys into a ApplicationUser table

Strictly speaking there should be a Check Constraint for both columns in every table

However this makes data diagrams unreadable and impossible to layout

The application is responsible for updating these columns, using the currently logged on 'ApplicationUser'

So....

... Should I use SQL Sever Check Constraints or rely on the Application to enforce Referential Integrity

Comment: what makes data diagrams unreadable? the foreign keys? I am not sure what you are asking. Do you want to remove foreign keys? Because as per your current design of all Audit tables linked with user table as foreign keys ensures referential integrity.

Comment: I have 85 tables, all of which have (at least) 2 columns which are foreign keys into ApplicationUser table. There are many other relationships between table too . So there are over 170 relationship lines on a data diagram just from the ApplicationUser table.  You can imagine how difficult it makes the diagram to read... !

Answer (score 2):

> Should I use...

Check constraints, always. No external app can enforce RI better than managing it internally in SQL Servers. That's why we use SQL Servers.

> data diagrams unreadable and impossible to layout

Try better layout software. In any case that should not affect your RI needs.

> Strictly speaking ...

You've answered your own question ...

**Follow up**

Should not matter if you use LINQ or some UI imposed type constraints. Your data has to be sound (satisfy referential integrity) first and foremost. Whether you do it in SQL or your app should not matter. Only that you need RI first before you tackle type safety (imposed by strongly typed models). There used to be video by Erik Meijer (the designer of LINQ) that addressed this very issue.

Comment: That is a "SQL developer" or purist point of view.  The application, being strongly typed and using LINQ to SQL, only gets an ID value from the ApplicationUser table in a single method. Should someone erroneously add code to use an arbitrary ID value either an enquiry on "who updated this value" will give an erroneous User (testing will  eliminate this) OR an error if the ID value is not in the ApplicationUser table (exception handling will handle this)

Comment: ...and not putting in constraints is a developer centric view... and I don't think the two camps will ever agree. Its possible that someone may introduce a bug that breaks integrity. Further, constraints and foreign keys can assist with performance.

Comment: However -  there are SQF for Maintainability such as Readability and Comprehensibility to consider. As a contractor often called in to "fix code" the biggest issue is understanding enough to find where the issue lies, and fix it without introducing new defects. In this case SQL RI would make this very difficult - Data Diagram almost impossible to decipher. . Commenting the User class and methods makes it very clear. In addition the Software Design document will document the RI decisions and reasons for them

Comment: @AndrewBingham as you say "...SQL RI would make this very difficult..." is true. But what is more true is that it is perfectly easy and logical to decipher a computer language 4 decades in the making instead of debugging in whatever is the flavor of the month language or being dependent on whatever was the documentation practices or the writing skills of the original programmer. SQL predates OO programming paradigm of classes and methods and will survive every language named after coffee flavors.

Comment: I think, on the contrary, SQL database and T-SQL are 4 decades old and both are now old-fashioned, clumsy, hard to use (compared to .Net) and have very poor SQFs. Languages, on the other hand have evolved and improved and  - as important - they are now integrated into Framework and environments (.Net and Visual Studio). Its interesting to see how hard is proving for Microsoft to achieve the same with SQL Server and T-SQL - SQL Management Station is gradually being bought into line with modern language environments but is still very poor

Comment: You are correct if your world is confined to dot net.

Comment: My world includes SQL Server - since v7

Answer (score -1):

As for another question I posted - I resolved this by using an ORM
(DevExpress XPO)

This abstracts away almost all the database - so that in an OO application there is (almost) never a need to even think about data storage of persisted objects